# Need help to use this

Tags: java, android

Can any one please make it simple or clear to me how the coder has used (this) here in the last line:

```
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{ 

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.main);

// Set up click listeners for all the buttons

View continueButton = findViewById(R.id.continue_button);

continueButton.setOnClickListener(this);<-----------------------------------

}
```

Comment: This looks like an android app. You should add android tag

Answer (score 5):

`this` i[s a reference to an instance of the class that the method belongs too](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html), specifically the **current** instance. This of `this` as a variable that always points to the **current** object.

> Within an instance method or a
>   constructor, this is a reference to
>   the current object — the object whose
>   method or constructor is being called.
>   You can refer to any member of the
>   current object from within an instance
>   method or a constructor by using this.

Comment: more specifically, it is the reference to >>the<< instance of the class on which the enclosing method is currently being run.

Comment: And to clarify even further, *this* refers to the `Activity` in which that piece of code was found.

Answer (score 2):

They have set the button's on-click listener to be `this`.

In other words, when the button is clicked, `onClick` will be invoked on *this* object.